# How to match a word surrounded by a prefix and suffix?

Tags: python, string, extract

Is there any regex to extract words from text that are surrounded by a certain prefix and suffix?

Example:

```
test[az5]test[az6]test
```

I need to extract the numbers surrounded by the prefix `[az` and the suffix `]`.

I'm a bit advanced in Python, but not really familiar with regex.

The desired output is:

```
5
6
```

Comment: is the prefix and suffix surrounding the digits always the same?

Comment: Yes, it is always [az , ]

Comment: See [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) -> [`re.findall(r"\[az(\d+)]", test_str)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurKDU9tULBVqFIKSY6sUojJkUzVomLqyS1uCS@uKQIKKEEYgOlTGOhDDMwA6goN7EkOSO1GKQ5VS8tMy8lMSdHA9kcHQWYOZpcXAVFmXklGlA9mv//AwA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the following regular expression:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\[az(\d+)\]', 'test[az5]test[az6]test')
['5', '6']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

txt = "test[az5]test[az6]test"
x = re.findall(r"\[az(?P<num>\d)\]", txt)
print(x)
```

Output
['5', '6']